# Update Android Widget at Midnight

Tags: android, widget

How to update Android widget everyday at midnight?? Below solution is formed by looking at other questions in stack overflow regarding to this topic.

1) schedule(context) is called when widget is created in the activity that extends AppWidgetProvider

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        schedule(context);
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

}
```

2) Schedule method should set a timer and alarm so that the widget gets updated at everyday at midnight. however this doesn't work.

```
protected void schedule(Context context) {
    final Intent i = new Intent(context, CalendarWidget.class);
    service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); 

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//This doesn't work
       // alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), service);
//This doesn't work either.
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, service);
    }
```

The solution doesn't work; and it is hard to test it because it can be tested only at midnight everyday; hence, the bounty. I will awarded it to the first person that makes it work.

Comment: why You have set the AlarmManager two times? delete one of them, just let the setRepeating method there

Comment: Both of them don't work. I tried both

Comment: ok, what exactly is not working? Is shedule() never be called? Or ist it called, but the AlarmManager doesn´t work?

Comment: Alam Manager doesn't work. My widget updates just fine, it is just he timer that doesn't work.

Comment: I am a little bit unclear about that You add a day to the Calendar. Make a Log. for the Calendar and check the time with calendar.getTime(); and look what´s the result. Maybe it is the wrong date.

Comment: @coolcool1994 Not sure if you still need this answered. If so, my first question: do you have the wake lock permission in the manifest?

Comment: I am not sure why you would need wake lock permission. I don't need the screen to stay on. I just want the widget to be updated - onReceive or onUpdate to be called at midnight everyday.

Comment: Could you add your CalendarWidget code? Also, review your project structure in order to make sure that both classes are in the same package.

Comment: Did you add <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver> in manifest?

Answer (score 10):

[denvercoder9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613395/2629367) works (sort of) but it could be simplified.  An `AppWidgetProvider` is already a `BroadcastReceiver`, so we can actually direct the intent back on the `AppWidgetProvider`, and override onReceive to handle it.

In your class extending `AppWidgetProvider`:

```
private static final String ACTION_SCHEDULED_UPDATE = "your.package.name.SCHEDULED_UPDATE";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SCHEDULED_UPDATE)) {
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] ids = manager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, AppWidget.class));
        onUpdate(context, manager, ids);
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // Do your updates...

    _scheduleNextUpdate(context);
}

private static void _scheduleNextUpdate(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager =
            (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // Substitute AppWidget for whatever you named your AppWidgetProvider subclass
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_SCHEDULED_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    // Get a calendar instance for midnight tomorrow.
    Calendar midnight = Calendar.getInstance();
    midnight.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    midnight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    // Schedule one second after midnight, to be sure we are in the right day next time this 
    // method is called.  Otherwise, we risk calling onUpdate multiple times within a few 
    // milliseconds
    midnight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    midnight.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    midnight.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

    // For API 19 and later, set may fire the intent a little later to save battery,
    // setExact ensures the intent goes off exactly at midnight.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, midnight.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, midnight.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

We need a custom intent action, because `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` doesn't update all widgets, even if you pass in the full array of ids as an extra under `AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS`.  It just updates the first widget created.

[Here is a project I'm working on](https://github.com/AlexanderOtavka/square-widget/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alexanderotavka/squarewidget/WidgetProvider.java) that implements a scheduled widget update similar to this.

Answer (score 5):

I created a date and time widget a while back. Below is the implementation:

In AppWidgetProvider class:

```
private boolean first_run = true;
public AlarmManager am;
public PendingIntent pi;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    first_run = context.getSharedPreferences("mywidet", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("first_run", true);
    if(first_run) {
        am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();

        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now();
        long triggerOffset = (24*60*60 - localTime.getHour()*60*60 - localTime.getMinute()*60 - localTime.getSecond())*1000;
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, current + triggerOffset, 86400000, pi);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("mywidet", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("first_run", false);
        editor.apply();
    }
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);
    }
}
```

in AlarmManagerBroadcasrReceiver class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
    //Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire();

    Log.d("widget", "in alarm manager. static method will come next");

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    //Release the lock
    wl.release();
}
```

**EDIT 1**

From API 19 onward all [`setReapeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) alarms are inexact. So, one might want to do the following:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexMin.getTimeInMillis()-current.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pendingIntent);
} else {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexMin.getTimeInMillis() - current.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

You can find the full implementation [here](https://github.com/rafid059/bangla-date-widget/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/io/sonnet/bangladatewidget/NewAppWidget.java).

Comment: I will try all the solutions here in the next 6 hours and award the bounty to the solution that works - if all work, the best solution will gets it. But honestly I hope just anything works

Comment: I forgot one thing:

use sharedpreferences to keep track of the boolean first_run.. silly mistake. sorry

Comment: This is just a snippet. His question was to update the widget precisely at 12 am everyday. That's what it does. I'm sure he can manage the control of the alarm by overriding onDisabled, onDeleted, onRestored and add necessary code  :)

Comment: How do you define: LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now();?

Comment: What do you mean by "define"? It's a library class of Java. It will give you the time of the location you are in currently.

Comment: Even though I awarded you the bounty, the app still doesn't get updated at midnight. Sigh....

Comment: And I think you forgot to add super.onReceive

Comment: Why would you add super.onReceive() ? Try updating the widget every minute for debugging purposes. See if it works.

Comment: @coolcool1994 There is one thing that you should know... if you are testing your app on api 19+ then setRepeating() wont work as it's defined. Read the doc to know more... Use setExact() instead and set the next alarm in onReceive()  ....  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: I am not sure how and it has been long time since i fixed this, but you can try with simplest thing first. Like make the widget update every seconds first - make a timer per say. Then everything else would work as it should. Go step-wise. hope this helps.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so that it helps the community.  :)  I don't need the solution because I've implemented it before but others will benefit from it.  :)